# KellermanSoftware CompareNetObjects, comparing collections of different types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, comparison

I am using CompareNetObjects for automated testing of my system. This has been useful in ensuring performance optimizations do not change the expected behavior of the system, and ensuring errors are not introduced.

When I have a collection that is declared in an abstract way, I expect to have the contents compared, not the collection itself; however, I do not see an option to enable this.

Class:

```
public class MustBeCorrect
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
[Fact] void IsCorrect()
{
    var obj1 = new MustBeCorrect
    {
        Name = "Kitty",
        Items = new string[]
        {
           "Collar",
           "Bell"
        }
    };
    var obj2 = new MustBeCorrect
    {
        Name = "Kitty",
        Items = new List<string>
        {
           "Collar",
           "Bell"
        }
    };
    comparer.Compare(obj1, obj2); // False!
}
```

The above two objects compare as not equal, even though the only difference between the two objects is one uses an array, and the other uses a list. In terms of my contract, however, these two seem as they should be considered equal to me.

How can I configure the comparison options to only compare the contents of collections, rather than the collection itself?

Answer (score 5):

There does not exist a way to do what you want specifically for collections.

However, there is an option you can set called `IgnoreObjectTypes` in the `ComparisonConfig`. It is default to `false`, but if you set it to `true`, it should give you the behavior you desire for your collections.

Be aware, this will ignore object types for all comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I found to make it work so far.
My solution consists in implementing a [Custom comparer](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects/wiki/Custom-Comparers) that ignores the generic argument of the collection when comparing `IEnumerable`s.

However, the drawback of this approach is that you lose the granularity of the returned `result.Differences`: if two lists have different elements, it won't tell you exactly how and which elements are different.

If someone could identify a way to implement this in the Custom Comparer, that'd be great.

```cs
public class OnlyIEnumContents : BaseTypeComparer
{
    public OnlyIEnumContents(RootComparer rootComparer) : base(rootComparer)
    {
    }

    public OnlyIEnumContents() : this(RootComparerFactory.GetRootComparer())
    {
    }

    public override bool IsTypeMatch(Type type1, Type type2)
    {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type1) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type2))
            return true;

        return type1 == type2;
    }

    public override void CompareType(CompareParms parms)
    {
        var ienum1 = parms.Object1 as IEnumerable;
        var ienum2 = parms.Object2 as IEnumerable;

        if (ienum1 != null && ienum2 != null)
        {
            List<object> list1 = new List<object>();
            List<object> list2 = new List<object>();

            foreach (var item in ienum1)
                list1.Add(item);

            foreach (var item in ienum2)
                list2.Add(item);

            // Compare the lists. 
            // Because all the list elements were boxed in a System.Object,
            // this only returns the differences between the single elements.
            CompareLogic compareLogic = new CompareLogic();
            ComparisonResult result = compareLogic.Compare(list1, list2);

            // This is where granularity is lost.
            // The official documentation https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects/wiki/Custom-Comparers
            // points that we should return `AddDifference(parms)`,
            // however I don't know how to get `parms` from a given `result` object.
            // Returning a single difference for the entire lists.
            if (!result.AreEqual)
                AddDifference(parms);
        }
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```cs
CompareLogic compareLogic = new CompareLogic();
compareLogic.Config.CustomComparers.Add(new OnlyIEnumContents());
ComparisonResult result = compareLogic.Compare(obj1, obj2);
```